# phpseclib not working to execute commands remotely

Tags: php, apache, shell, phpseclib, sudoers

I am stuck with a problem in php for the last 3 days. couldn't find a solution yet.

I have a Cent OS remote machine and an Ubuntu local machine. I have a php script named `test.php` in my local machine so that I want to run some Linux commands in the remote machine using that php script. I used phpseclib for connecting to remote machine. The following is the php script `test.php`.

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', NET_SSH2_LOG_COMPLEX);

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('10.3.2.0');
if (!$ssh->login('makesubdomain','abcdabcd')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}
echo $ssh->exec('/usr/local/listdomain.backup/test/makedir.sh');
?>
```

I can't use `root` user here since root login has been disabled in remote cent os machine.
So I created this `makesubdomain` user and gave sudo privileges, that too without password by adding `makesubdomain ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` in `/etc/sudoers` file.The below one is the shell script which resides in `10.3.2.0`

```
sudo -H sh -c '
    mkdir /usr/local/testdir
    if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
        echo  "success";
    else
        echo "not success";
    fi
'
```

But now when I run the php script from terminal using command `php test.php` it showing error `sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`. Ultimately, What shall I need to do with `test.php` and `makedir.sh` for creating a directory `testdir` as specified in .sh file using the given php script with user `makesubdomain`. Please advice as I am a very beginner in php.

(Note : I can run the `makedir.sh` file successfully in the remote machine, with the command `sudo ./makedir` as user `makesubdomain`, that too without prompting sudo password)

**EDIT**

I had commented `Defaults    requiretty` in `/etc/sudoers` as given in http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/201211-sudo-sorry-you-must-have-tty-run-sudo.html, and it is working fine. Can i have any other option without doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `$ssh->enablePTY()` before doing `$ssh->exec()`.